# Is jQuery Mobile CSS Specificity W3C Standards Compliant?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, standards

Not that I need an answer, as the short answer would be **NO**. I pose this question more because it is an issue that is not addressed from the jQuery forums to Google code forums to right here at StackOverflow.

I've been a programmer since I got my first Commodore 16 that used a standard cassette tape recorder to back up data (yes... I'm that old). Since then, there has been the long and tiresome battle to create universally compliant standards in coding practices in many programming languages, with the W3C being the closest we have come to date.

In my own opinion, and after writing a couple of apps with jQuery Mobile (jQm), I see jQm as a good idea that was badly implemented just for this very reason. jQm has decided to implement their own CSS in a non-compliant manner, leaving the developer fighting the hi-jacking of their own 'standards compliant' supplemental CSS by jQm. Remember folks, the C in CSS is for 'cascading', meaning that a style declaration that follows a previous style
declaration will take precedence over that style which came before it. Not the case with jQm CSS, making it **NON** standards-compliant.

I have experimented with many ways of implementing my own standards-compliant CSS around the CSS hi-jacking behavior of jQm (external CSS files loaded after jQuery's CSS, @imports, in-line styles... you name it) to no avail. Outside of actually over-riding the styles contained in the jQm CSS with CSS of my own after jQm CSS has been loaded.
I mean... doesn't this completely negate any benefit of using jQm in the first place?

Points to my argument. If I have to either 'over-ride' jQm's CSS in my own 'standards-compliant' CSS, or tweak the jQm CSS itself (which will then remove the advantage of being to able to import your existing jQm CSS into Theme Roller at a later date to add another style), then I may as well write my own UI to begin with.

I can write my own transitions easily enough using jQuery and CSS3 transitions, so there go any benefits from using jQm's transitions. jQm's translation of mouse events to touch controls are already becoming obsolete, as most major browsers are already perfecting this themselves with the advent of tablets and touch-screen laptops into the desktop world environments, but unlike jQm, in a standards-compliant manner. Then there is jQm's default ajax navigation behavior, that I can easily implement myself using jQuery's own rich XMLHttpRequest shorthand methods ($.ajax, $.get, $.post, and $.getJSON) with lower overhead and better performance.
So why use jQm at all?!

I myself am done with jQm, as the time I have spent fighting jQm's non-compliant CSS behavior, exceeds the time it takes me to just write my own standards-compliant UI in the first place. I am a firm believer in standards compliancy, having had to battle non-compliant apps (like IE... oh-no, did I say that in my out-loud voice!) for more than two decades.

Myself... I will be writing all my apps using standards-compliant HTML5 and CSS3 from now on, which has the additional benefit of being able to easily deploy through different mobile devices by wrapping my compliant coding in the mobile devices own SDK's that are designed to do just that, with yet another powerful benefit of being able to use the mobile device's own features (such as accelerometer, compass, camera, etc...).

I would love to hear feedback on this issue, as I always keep an open-mind, and love a good round table discussion that has me rethinking decisions I have made myself based on my own experience.

UPDATE
Here is an example and a jsfiddle that describes what I am referencing in this question.

```
<style>
.my_link a:link{ color:#00cc00 }
</style>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<p><a href="#">
Link using default jQm CSS</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="my_link">
Link using CSS class declared in HEAD after jQm CSS</a></p>
<p><a href="#"> style="color:#00cc00">
Link using inline CSS declared after jQm CSS</a></p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ephiphany/S7NuK/

Comment: The easy answer is, No, jQuery Mobile and jQuery UI are not standards compliant. They can't be if they are going to work on all browsers and devices because not all browsers and devices follow standards.

Comment: is this supposed to be a question or just a rant?

Comment: As far as jqm css overriding your css, you just aren't making your css declarations specific enough.

Comment: It is a free code, I would simply extend/modify as per my need. And as far as CSS, you should be able to override those rules by declaring a more specific CSS rule. The cascading is only if you the specificity is same in both CSS.

Comment: ("You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.")[http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask]

Comment: @Kevin B. First, I have had not had any problems with any major browsers outside of IE adhering to W3C standards compliant coding for both HTML5 and CSS3 to date. Second, unless you actually over-ride the jQm CSS with your own CSS loaded after jQm's using the same class names declared in jQm's CSS (such as re-declaring .ui-bar for example in your own CSS)... then your CSS will be over-ridden by jQm. You can see this if you nest a div and declare a width of 100% inside a jQm div, and the nested div will take the value of the outer div, rather than the div it is relative too.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe. I'm sorry you feel addressing standards compliancy is just a rant, as I feel it paramount to good coding practices.

Comment: @Epiphany *"outside of IE"* that's where the problem lies. JQM still has to work in IE. JQM isn't just for mobile devices, the goal of JQM is to work in all devices *including desktop* http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/. Again on the css. JQM doesn't change how css works. Read up on css specificity. Here's a link to the first result I found on google: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ If you make selectors specific enough, they will override JQM's styles.

Comment: If you don't like JQM, don't use it. A lot of people don't like it including me.

Comment: @madth3. I feel addressing standards complicancy as not just practical, but essential. Developing a consensus as what should be compliant results in better coding practices for all, which is now more important than it ever was with the focus on newer web technologies being based on interactivity.

Comment: Read the FAQ. Whatever the importance that standards might have, SO does not intend to be a place to discuss things but to help in solvable problems.

Comment: @Kevin B. I know that jQm isn't just for mobile devices, and it was that very cross-platform ability with one set of source code that aroused my interest in jQm. And once again, you can not over-ride jQm's CSS behavior as you claim. For example, try asserting another color on an anchor with an inline style... it won't work, unless you over-ride the specific class where the anchor lives in the jQm CSS (such as .ui-link in the jQm CSS for the document body).

Comment: @madth3. If you were to research this issue yourself (as I have for several weeks) you will find this is a problem being experienced quite widespread in the developer community. I never address a question unless I find that it is a wide-spread problem.

Comment: @Epiphany it works for me, I don't know what you are talking about. Does the given anchor tag have child span elements that have a css defined color?

Comment: @KevinB. My bad, as you are right about the inline CSS, although inline CSS is against best programming practices these days. There is still an issue with any other CSS type being over-ridden by jQm. I'm updating my question with a jsfiddle to show what I am talking about

Comment: @Epiphany Given your example, you would have to make your selector more specific. Specificity goes in this order: Inline > ID > Class > Tagname/psudo element. JQM uses class class, so you have to at least use class class, or an id. which style was declared first only matters if the two are equal as far as specificity goes. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/S7NuK/1/

Comment: @madth3. OK... now you have what you are requesting, and I would appreciate a more introspective look at this problem before being so quick to shut it down.

Comment: better sample: http://jsfiddle.net/S7NuK/2/

Comment: @KevinB. Thank you Kevin for your open-minded input and feedback, that has resulted in a solution. I'd give you an extra point on that alone if I could!

Comment: If you update your question to be a question about CSS specificity, it would be a valid SO question and won't be closed. That and my answer would fit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override JQM styles (or any styles for that matter) your css selector needs to be more specific than the one used by JQM's stylesheet.

For example, given the following page with 1 link:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-url="/Ephiphany/S7NuK/show/" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-a ui-page-active" style="min-height: 209px;">
  <p class="my_p"><a href="#" class="my_link ui-link">Link using default jQm CSS</a></p>
</div>
```

JQM has this style:

```
.ui-body-a .ui-link:link {
    color: #2489CE;
}
```

CSS Specificity is a priority system, in that there are tiers of precedence: Inline Styles > ID > Class/attribute/state > Tagname/psudoelement

With this in mind, we either need an ID, or we need to use two classes. For example, this would override it if it comes after the JQM stylesheet:

```
.my_p .my_link:link { 
    color: #00cc00
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S7NuK/2/

Don't forget about `:visited` `:hover` `:active` etc.